# Reference for calculating definite integral involving sines

Tags: integration, elementary-proofs

Recently I accidentally discovered a simple, elementary derivation of the following identity, valid for any $n,k \in \mathbb N$:
\begin{align*}
 \frac1\pi \int_0^\pi {\rm d}x \left(\!\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\!\right)^{\!\!k}
 = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i \binom{k}{i} \binom{k(n{+}1)/2-1-ni}{k-1}
 \ .
 \tag*{(1)}
\end{align*}
$\binom ab$ are the binomial coefficients, with the slightly non-standard convention that $\binom ab = 0$ whenever $a<b$ or $a \notin \mathbb N_0$, which implies for instance that terms with $i \geq k/2$ in the sum on the right are always zero (i.e., $k$ as upper bound could be replaced by $\lfloor k/2 \rfloor$), and that for even $n$ and odd $k$ the whole expression $(1)$ becomes zero.

I looked for integral $(1)$ in [Gradshteyn & Ryzhik](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) but only found the case $k=1$ (see 3.612-2. on p. 391). 
I also tried Mathematica, which succeeded to do the integral $(1)$ for specific $n,k \in \mathbb N$, but for instance could not do the cases $k=1$ or $k=2$ for general $n \in \mathbb N$, while according to $(1)$ we simply have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac1\pi \int_0^\pi {\rm d}x \, \frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}
 = \begin{cases}
 0 & n \text{ even} \\ 1 & n \text{ odd} 
 \end{cases}
 \ , 
 \\
 &\frac1\pi \int_0^\pi {\rm d}x \left(\!\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\!\right)^{\!\!2}
 = n
 \ .
 \tag*{(2)}
\end{align*}
Can anybody point out a reference where the integral $(1)$ or a similar one is calculated?

---

**Addendum (Mai 9, 2019)**

Below I describe an elegant and completely elementary way to prove $(1)$, which does not invoke the residue theorem or Chebyshev polynomials. 
I have also posted this idea [here on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-that-for-all-integer-n-displaystyle-int_0-pi-2-left-frac-text-sin-nx-text-sin-x-right-4-dx-displaystyle-frac-pi-6-n-2n-2+1/answer/Dierk-Bormann).

First, let me call the above integral $I_{k,n}$ (for arbitrary $k,n \in \mathbb N$), and re-write it in the form 
\begin{align*}
 I_{k,n} = \frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d}x \left(\!\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\!\right)^{\!\!k}
 \ .
 \tag*{(3)}
\end{align*}
It is convenient to introduce a complex variable $z={\rm e}^{{\rm i}x}$ and write 
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}
 = \frac{z^{n}-z^{-n}}{z-z^{-1}}
 = z^{n-1} + z^{n-3} + \cdots + z^{-n+3} + z^{-n+1}
 \ .
 \tag*{(4)}
\end{align*}
The integrand in $(3)$ is therefore equal to $( z^{n-1} + z^{n-3} + \cdots + z^{-n+3} + z^{-n+1} )^k$, which can be expanded in a sum of integer powers of $z$. 
Since for any integer $q$ we have $\frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d}x\, z^q = \frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d}x\, {\rm e}^{{\rm i}qx} = \delta_{q0}$, our integral $I_{k,n}$ is simply equal to the coefficient of the $z^0$ term in the expansion of the integrand or, in other words, by the coefficient of the $t^\frac{k(n-1)}2$ term ($t=z^2$) of the polynomial
\begin{align*}
 \left( 1 + t + \cdots + t^{n-1} \right)^{k} 
 = \left( \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} t^{\nu} \right)^{\!\!k}
 \ .
 \tag*{(5)}
\end{align*}
The problem has thus been reduced to a purely combinatorial one, namely, to count the number of terms proportional to $t^\frac{k(n{-}1)}2$ in the expansion of $\rm (5)$. 
Obviously, whenever $k(n{-}1)$ is odd, this coefficient is simply zero, but for even $k(n{-}1)$ the situation is more interesting.
To count the number of terms  in $\rm (5)$ which are proportional to the $m$th power of $t$ (with the particular case $m = \frac{k(n-1)}2$ in mind), we replace the $k$th power of the $\nu$ sum by a joint sum over $k$ ``independent copies'' of $\nu$, denoted $\nu_1$, $\nu_2$, ..., $\nu_k$: 
\begin{align*}
 \left( \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} t^\nu \right)^{\!\!k}
 = \sum_{\nu_1,\dots,\nu_k=0}^{n-1} t^{\sum_{j=1}^k \nu_j} 
 \ .
 \tag*{(6)}
\end{align*}
A given term in this multiple sum equals $t^m$ if and only if $\sum_{j=1}^k \nu_j = m$, which implies that the coefficient of $t^m$ in $(6)$ can be expressed as follows (here $\# S \in \mathbb N_0$ denotes the cardinality of a finite set $S$):
\begin{align*}
 I_{k,n} = \#\! \left\{(\nu_1,...,\nu_k) \in \mathbb N_0^k \! : \ \forall_i  (\nu_i < n) \text{ and } {\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^k \nu_i = m}\right\} 
 \ ,
 \tag*{(7)}
\end{align*}
which is positive for any integer $m$ between $0$ and $k(n-1)$, and zero otherwise. 
If it weren't for the conditions $\nu_i < n$, $(7)$ would for any $m \in \mathbb N_0$ simply be given by the well-known, elementary combinatorial result 
\begin{align*}
 \#\! \left\{(\nu_1,...,\nu_k) \in \mathbb N_0^k \! : \ {\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^k \nu_i = m }\right\} 
 = \binom{k-1+m}{k-1}
 \ .
 \tag*{(8)}
\end{align*}
We can reformulate $(6)$ in a way such as to avoid the constraints $\nu_i < n$, applying the following trick: we re-write the sum within parentheses on the left-hand side of $(6)$ as 
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} t^\nu
 = \left( 1 - t^n \right) \sum_{\nu=0}^\infty t^\nu
 \ ,
 \tag*{(9)}
\end{align*}
which "removes'' the upper limit in the $\nu$ sum.
Raising this to the $k$th power and using the usual binomial expansion $\left( 1- t^n \right)^{\!k} = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} t^{jn}$ then leads to 
\begin{align*}
 \left( \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1} t^\nu \right)^{\!\!k}
 = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} \sum_{\nu_1,\dots,\nu_k=0}^\infty t^{\sum_{j=1}^k \nu_j + jn} 
 \ .
 \tag*{(10)}
\end{align*}
The same argument as before in the step from $(6)$ to $(7)$ leads to combinatorial factors of the simpler form $(8)$, now with $m$ replaced by $m - jn$, and so the final, general result for integer values of $m = \frac{k(n-1)}2$ becomes (note that always $\lfloor m/n \rfloor < k$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the largest integer $\leq x$):
\begin{align*}
 I_{k,n} = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor m/n \rfloor} (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} \binom{k-1+m-jn}{k-1}
 \ ,
 \tag*{(11)}
\end{align*} 
which is trivially equivalent to $(1)$, concluding the proof.

There may be ways to further simplify expression $(11)$, but I would rather doubt it.

*Some special cases:*

1. For $k=2$, we have $\lfloor m/n \rfloor =0$ and so $I_{2,n} = \binom n1 = n$,  for all  $n \in \mathbb N$.
2. For $k=4$ (and $n\geq2$), we have $\lfloor m/n \rfloor =1$ and so
   \begin{align*}
    I_{4,n} &= \binom{2n+1}3 - 4\binom{n+1}3
    \\
    &= \frac16 \big[ (2n+1)2n(2n-1) - 4(n+1)n(n-1) \big]
    \\
    &= \frac13 n \big( 2n^2+1 \big)
    \ .
    \tag*{(12)}
   \end{align*} 
   The last expression in $(12)$ is obviously correct also for $n=1$, and thus for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Try  this . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials    You are dealing with  Chebysev polynomials of the 2nd kind and they have so many nice properties that I am not surprised  an integral formula of the kind you found exists.

Comment: The integrand is even, so that it is half of the integral over the complete period. Take $z=e^{ix}$ as the new variable, and apply the binomial theorem followed by the Cauchy theorem. It is a mere exercise in complex analysis... I'd suspect that not all such exercises have references...

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu: Thank you for this suggestion, I admit I had not thought of this connection.

Comment: @Wadim Zudilin: Thank you for reminding me that this is a "mere exercise". Please note that I didn't claim it to be difficult to do, quite on the contrary. What puzzled me was that I still couldn't find it in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, nor was apparently Mathematica able to do it (which is otherwise quite good at elementary integrals). So I became curious to know whether this integral actually occurs somewhere in the literature and in which context.

Comment: Dear Dierk, I also had a look at the Prudnikov-Brychkov-Marichev 3-volume edition, where the particular instance $k=1$ is recorded but not more... Yes, I understand your question and also hope that my comment is understood: there is nothing dangerous in asking about references for such stuff but they can indeed be non existing because of the exercise nature of the problem. BTW, if you have a tricky (but nice) solution to your problem, which does not involve complex analysis, it may still be of interest.

Comment: Thanks Wadim for explaining, your comment came indeed across somewhat rough (to me) ;-).  I actually did the integral without using complex analysis, but my argument is essentially equivalent to what you suggest (just not using the elegant complex analysis language), so yours is probably nicer.  If I find time I may add it later as an "answer" to my question.

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but the argument belongs in an answer and not as an addendum to the question.

Comment: @Matt F.: As you may notice if you re-read my question carefully, I was not asking for a proof (which is not difficult, as I pointed out in the first sentence) but for a *literature reference* to this or related problems. Thus, my addendum actually does *not* answer the question. Instead, my idea with it was to demonstrate that the proof is indeed not difficult (although apparently not well-known, otherwise the integral would have been listed in Gradshteyn-Ryzhik or Prudnikov-Brychkov-Marichev).

Comment: Tagging the question reference-request would help to clarify.